# Java Array Searching

Tags: java, arrays, string, search

In java an array has three words `{'bad','bat','hat'}`. I have to write a function which will search like dictionary from array.

Example: If I search **at** then the function will return all the words which have **at** in it (like `bat` and `hat` will be shown in the output) and if I search a single character character then it will return all those words which have that character. Is there any built-in function available in Java?

e.g: `if (string.contains(item1) || string.contains(item2) || string.contains(item3))`

Comment: [`String::contains(CharSequence)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-)? [idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/](http://idownvotedbecau.se/noresearch/)

Comment: What do you have so far?

Comment: Also please format your question properly, both in outer form and in semantics. E.g. something in single quotations (`'`) normally represents a `char` in Java. For `String`s, double quotations (`"`) should be used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could stream the array, and filter using [`String::contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence-).

```
String[] words = {"bad", "bat","hat"};
String filter = "at";

List<String> list = Stream.of(words)
        .filter(word -> word.contains(filter))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

Answer (score 0):

For Java 8, the [streaming method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48079899/2074605) would be preferred because it can utilize multiple processors. For earlier versions of Java, the following methods could be used. The first uses the `contains` method, the second uses regular expressions and might be more useful to you.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class SearchTest
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final String[] words = {"bad", "bat", "hat", "hate"};
        final String filter = "at";
        final String pattern = ".*at$"; // regex matching only strings that end with "at"

        System.out.println(".contains");
        final String[] results1 = SearchTest.search(filter, words);

        for (String match : results1)
        {
            System.out.println(match);
        }

        // regex
        System.out.println("Regular Expression");
        final String[] results2 = SearchTest.match(pattern, words);

        for (String match : results2)
        {
            System.out.println(match);
        }
    }

    public static String[] search(final String substring, final String[] words)
    {
        final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String word : words)
        {
            if (word.contains(substring))
            {
                matches.add(word);
            }
        }

        return matches.toArray(new String[0]);
    }

    public static String[] match(final String regex, final String[] words)
    {
        final List<String> matches = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String word : words)
        {
            if (word.matches(regex))
            {
                matches.add(word);
            }
        }

        return matches.toArray(new String[0]);
    }
}
```