# How do you compare a substring with array of strings in Java

Tags: java

How can we compare a substring with the strings mentioned in an array using Java programming?
Eg.  Check if "AC" is in { Apple - AC, Ball, Cat, Doctor........ ,}
This should return Apple - AC, as it contains AC as a substring.

Comment: This falls into the category of "gimme the codez". So I suggest you to try something first by yourself and come back here when you have a real question or problem

Comment: Somewhat similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48079785/java-array-searching/48079899

Answer (score 0):

So, next time you post on stackoverflow, be sure to list out what you've tried before and which parts you are having trouble with, instead of just asking us to do it completely for you.

```
public static String findWithSubstring(String[] arr, String sub) {
    for (int i=0; i<arr.length(); i++) {
        if (arr[i].contains(sub)) {
            return arr[i];
        }
    }
    return "";
}
```

So, Thunder has the right approach, but it will return true no matter which element has the substring in it. The question asked "this should return "Apple -AC".

Answer (score 0):

```
String[] words = {"Apple - AC", "Ball", "Cat", "Doctor"};
String filter = "AC";
```

If you want all matching words:

```
List<String> list = Stream.of(words)
        .filter(word -> word.contains(filter))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

System.out.println(list);
```

If you are only interested in the first matching word:

```
Optional<String> firstMatch = Stream.of(words)
        .filter(word -> word.contains(filter))
        .findFirst();

System.out.println(firstMatch);
```